# OpenGL ES version in compile time

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I need to know the OpenGL ES version in compile time on Android NDK (C++). On desktops I know that is

```
#ifdef OPENGL_ES==1
```

or

```
#ifdef OPENGL_ES==2
```

but on android I don't know which constant is.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't know at compile time what versions will be supported on the devices you'll be running your app on.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 became mandatory on Android devices a while back, but I don't remember which release, so after a certain point you can just assume it exists.  All devices that support GLES 2.x also support 1.x.  The GLES requirements can be specified with Android Market flags if you don't want to do runtime detection.  Grafika's EGL management classes demonstrate how to select GLES2, or GLES3 if available.  (The sources are in Java, but it's a direct translation to native -- https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/EglCore.java .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 was introduced in API 8 (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). 3.0 was introduced in API 18. However, which version of GL you are compiling with depends on which GL header you include. To determine whether a desired header exists, you must check the `__ANDROID_API__` macro from api-level.h.

```
    #include <android/api-level.h>
    #if __ANDROID_API__ >= 18
    # include <GLES3/gl3.h>
    #elif __ANDROID_API__ >= 8
    # include <GLES2/gl2.h>
    #else
    # include <GLES/gl.h>
    #endif
```

If later in your code, you want to know which version of the GLES headers you have included (and thus available), you can inspect whether these macros are defined and true: `GL_ES_VERSION_3_0`, `GL_ES_VERSION_2_0`. Eg:

```
    #if defined(GL_ES_VERSION_3_0) && GL_ES_VERSION_3_0
    // gles3 version
    #elif defined(GL_ES_VERSION_2_0) && GL_ES_VERSION_2_0
    // gles2 version
    #else
    // gles version
    #endif
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I will use cmake for the build process and using it I can set preprocessor constants in compile time.

Comment: It would be strange to set these preprocessor macros with CMake (which I use as well), as they are contained in header files inside the Android NDK. For instance, if you set `__ANDROID_API__`, it will override the actual version of the NDK you are building with.

Comment: I will add new constants to the compiler to check what opengl version is, because I need cross-platform compile for this app.